# Get dimension of screen area used by activity

Tags: android, android-activity

How do I determine the dimensions (width and height) of an activity during onCreate. The dimension must not be that of the entire screen but only of area that is used by the activity. A few methods I tried posted on SO all end up giving the device's maximum screen sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried (not exactly onCreate):

```
activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.yourRootView);    
        activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                   //activityRootView.getHeight();
                   //...
                }
             }
        });
```

And ofcourse, your activitys main layout has to match parent or fill content

Comment: I tried out your code. It returns the screen's size (320 x 480). That's wrong. It should be less than that. The status bar takes up some of the height. Therefore the activity's height should be less.

Comment: @AndroidDev status bar is not part of your activity

Comment: @AndroidDev can it be the title?

Comment: @AndroidDev try removing the title : `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

Comment: The status bar (where the battery, wifi, clock is located) is not part of the activity and therefore the height of the activity MUST be less than the total screen height. So if my screen's height is 480 pixels, then the screen height has to be less than that. Your code returns 480 pixels.

Comment: My activity has no title section.

Comment: @AndroidDev what about method: `activityRootView.getHeight();` ?

Comment: Yes that works. I updated your code to show that. However, I will wait until a better solution comes because your solution requires a time period for the layout manager to expand the layout making this awkward to use in onCreate when you really need to know the dimensions without having to wait. That should be possible. Android clearly knows what the maximum space available is, so it should be possible to obtain that information.

Comment: @AndroidDev in Android, when you create a view, you do not know about its dimensions, until it is fully rendered on the screen. Except for the cases when you explicitly define dimensions

Comment: But you are missing the point. Android knows already BEFORE it creates your view the dimension of the area to create the view, so it should be possible to obtain that information.

Comment: @AndroidDev after reading and analyzing http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html i think that you are wrong by saying "Android knows already BEFORE it creates your view the dimension of the area to create the view". But I am sure that if you call `requestLayout` method on your view, then you will be able to get some (maybe) more accurate information about your future view, because then you would `initiate` a layout which would force the view to re-measure itself and its descendants

Answer (score 0):

The entire user content goes to `android.R.id.content` so what you can do is

```
final Rect rectgle = new Rect();
LinearLayout mContent = (LinearLayout)findViewById(android.R.id.content).getParent();
mContent.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectgle);
// and use
//rectgle.top;
//rectgle.left
//rectgle.right
```

this includes action bar if you want to exclude actionbar also directly use

```
//findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```

which returns a `FrameLayout`