# How Android renders layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

I am wondering, in Android, when you specify `setContentView(R.layout.some_layout);` thing to note from docs:

> This view is placed directly into the activity's view hierarchy

in which way Android renders all views in `R.layout.some_layout`?

How does Android calculate all the dimensions of views?

I am asking because I know that it is a common courtesy to wait until all views are rendered and already then try to get desired dimensions of views

Question popped up during a small discussion under [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17966146/1276374) answer, when user @AndroidDev stated the following:

> Android knows already BEFORE it creates your view the dimension of the
>   area to create the view

And I started thinking that it actually might be true. Either Android already knows in advance all the measurements or runs a recursive measurement function after each and every new Laoyout, UI component being appended to the Activitys root view, which updates some sort of temporary pointers where to insert the next view (that is how i used to imagine it)

Comment: have you ever looked at `hierarchyviewer` resides in `\android-sdk\tools` directory?

Comment: @ChintanRathod no, doesn't it show the hierarchy after views creation?

Comment: Isn't my answer helpful to you?

Comment: @ChintanRathod let me watch the video and to read all the documents and then I will be certain if your answer was helpful to me or not

Comment: @ChintanRathod but it seems legit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hierarchy Viewer is a visual tool that can be used to inspect your application user interfaces in ways that allow you to identify and improve your layout designs.

Check articles **[here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-tools-using-the-hierarchy-viewer/)** and **[here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-tools-leveraging-the-hierarchy-viewer-for-ui-profiling/)**.

Developer's site has provided **[Optimizing Your UI](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html)**

**Edit**

Red to know how [Android Draws View](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html).

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v9S5EO7CLjo) is video by Google I/O 2011: Accelerated Android Rendering.

Comment: Hierarchy Viewer does provide lots of information, but it does not say how Android renders views

Comment: Like for example, from View Properties in Hierarchy Viewer, `mMeasuredHeight` why it has 53 value (in my case)? Where does this value come from? How this value is measured?